# Remove the G++ link to clang++ on High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, macports

It's a well-known fact that the `g++` command actually links to `clang++`, from the llvm toolkit. Problem is, every makefile that uses `g++` has to point explicitly to the location, and unless my end user has brew on linux, the path will be different.

So my question is, how do I set the system up, so that `/bin/g++` actually points to a version installed from either macports or homebrew.

I know that Apple have deprecated GNU C Compiler a long time ago, and that this is the way it has been, but creating a hard-link to clang is the most stupid solution I could think of, and I'd like to have my system working as it should.

Comment: This is why automaker,waf,scones  and cmake do tests to find c++ and other tools and their capabilities so that they build on machines with different paths. Simple makefiles are not sufficient.

Comment: How about if I wrote a maths textbook where both 4 and 5 meant 5. And that’s not Really a problem, since every time you mean 4, you could write 3+1. And yeah calculators understand this, and will give you the right results, which is why knowing how to count is not sufficient.

Comment: Different machines have different C++ compilers and they are in different places. e.g. on one box you have /opt/bin/cc amd /usr/bin/cc - you cannot assume that the C++ compiler is in /usr/bin/g++

Comment: @Mark, you’re missing the point. I’m fine with compilers having different locations based on installation method. I’m fine with there being no way of installing gcc on Mac OS, but I’m not fine with masquerading llvm as GCC and calling that a solution. You’re absolutely right, I can’t assume that a compiler is at one location, but I usually don’t have to. The OS knows where it is installed, and usually it doesn’t lie to your face about the location.

Comment: The OS does not know where the compiler is it does mot tell you at all anythjing about the compiler. If I want gcc I use macports and could have several versions around at once so have to choose the one I want. (When I learnt C++ the comment was always compile under two different compilers to get the best error messages and make sure you were writing standard code.) There is no one place for a compiler

Comment: @Mark, I'm sorry, but you're arguing out of ignorance. On Unix-like systems, the convention is, that if no path to a POSIX compliant executable `foo` is provided, the shell, is to interpret that as `/bin/foo`. Whether or not that's the actual location of `foo` or just a hardlink to wherever you've put your executable is immaterial. What's important is that `foo` is some implementation of the program that has the relevant manpage, i.e. you should not have `/bin/vi` point to `emacs`. (continued)

Comment: @Mark, So, on *every* Linux system, if you type in `vi` or you invoke a makefile that calls `vi`, you're guaranteed to run a program that behaves like `vi` even though it could be, e.g. a symlink to vim in compatibility mode.

Comment: @Mark, My problem with what they've done, is that this breaks one of the well established Unix conventions, described in the core utilities man page. How? `clang` while is a compiler, behaves differently. It has no OpenMP support, it produces differently formatted warning/error messages, which breaks every program that relies on the convention working properly in every case where `gcc` acts differently to `clang`. 

One last point. The OS **knows** where every command-line utility is located. Why? Because `which g++` doesn't print `I don't know where g++ is` it prints `/usr/bin/g++`.

Comment: which g++ is not given by the OS it is by the shell - Note if I do have gcc installed which g++ will return /opt/local/bin/g++ Note that MacOS meats UNIX standards Linux does not

Comment: Few mistakes. `which` is a Unix core utility, independent of the shell you're using. Now, you should do two things, `g++ --version` and `--version` on `/opt/local/bin/g++`. At least one of them is `clang`, in my case - both. That's the **problem.**

Comment: Also, the only place I could find substantiation of your claim that Mac OS meets unix standards and Linux doesn't, was that Mac OS has Unix O3 specification. To meet it, you need to have paid the open Group. It's a fishy claim. 

Why? Because the only connection Mac OS X ever had with Unix was BSD. In fact, the kernel is Mach, not BSD or a modification thereof. But according to that very same certification, BSD isn't Unix, while it is the **oldest** surviving descendant of the Unix family. This is the kind of marketing that gives apple a bad reputation.

Comment: The point was more that Linux does things one way other Unixes do it another - neither is THE way to do it you have to deal with these cases - and that includes having multiple c++ on your machine

Comment: @Mark, You're defending the indefensible. On every Unix or Unix-like operating system, there's a system of conventions, that `man foo` returns the manpage for the `foo` program, wherever it is. The convention is also, that `/bin/foo` or simply `foo` invoked from the command-line will point to an implementation of `foo` that complies with the description of `man foo`. Now, the hardlink breaks all statements in that condition: `clang` isn't an implementation of `g++` it fails where `g++` doesn't. `man g++` describes Gnu C++ compiler, not Clang. And you can't fix it without compromising the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run this command in the Terminal:

```
ln -f /usr/local/bin/g++-8.2.0 /bin/g++
```

where you need to replace "/usr/local/bin/g++-8.2.0" with the actual full path to the g++ executable, you want to use. This varies depending on if you use macports or homebrew, what you set your homebrew prefix to, which version of g++ you install, etc.

Comment: `ln: /bin/g++: Operation not permitted`. I even tried `sudo rm -rf /bin/g++` to remove the hardlink. It exits with 0 (as if it had removed the hardlink), but `which g++` still brings you the same file.

Comment: You’ll need to disable SIP to make changes to system files. Reboot in recovery mode, issue the command in my answer after disabling SIP and then re-enable it.